# Get many to many from polymorphic table ID

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5.1

Using Laravel 5.1, how can I get `Dialogs` from a `M:M` relationship with a Polymorphic table.

When I load `tasks`, it loads the appropriate `npc`. This relationship between `tasks` and `npcs` is a Polymorphic relation.

So I created another `M:M` table, `dialog_npcseventsmorphable`, that links the `dialog_id` to the `npcs_events_morphable_id` on `npcs_events_morphable` table, but it is not loading the `dialogs`.

`$task = Task::findOrFail(1);`

npcs_events_morphable:

```
 id | npc_id | morphable_id | morphable_type |     created_at      |     updated_at      |    published_at     
----+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
  1 |      1 |            1 | App\Task       | 2018-05-20 04:45:24 | 2018-05-20 04:45:24 | 2018-05-20 04:45:24
  2 |      2 |            1 | App\Activity   | 2018-05-20 04:45:24 | 2018-05-20 04:45:24 | 2018-05-20 04:45:24
  3 |      3 |            1 | App\Battle     | 2018-05-20 04:45:24 | 2018-05-20 04:45:24 | 2018-05-20 04:45:24
```

dialog_npcseventsmorphable:

```
 dialog_id | npcs_events_morphable_id (<-- id on 'npcs_events_morphable' table)
-----------+--------------------------
         1 |                        1
         2 |                        1
         3 |                        2
         4 |                        2
         5 |                        3
         6 |                        3
         7 |                        3
         8 |                        3
         9 |                        3
```

Task:

```
class Task extends BaseModel
{
    protected $with = ['npcs', ...];

    public function npcs()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Npc', 'morphable', 'npcs_events_morphable');
    }
}
```

Npc:

```
class Npc extends BaseModel
{
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Task', 'morphable', 'npcs_events_morphable');
    }
    ...
}
```

Dialog:

```
class Dialog extends BaseModel
{
    public function npcs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(NpcsEventsMorphable::class, 'dialog_npcseventsmorphable');
    }
    ...
}
```

NpcsEventsMorphable:

```
class NpcsEventsMorphable extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'npcs_events_morphable';

    protected $with = ['dialogs'];

    public function dialogs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Dialog::class, 'dialog_npcseventsmorphable');
    }
}
```

}